# PHP change language of current site

Tags: php

I am working on changing language without leaving current site for PHP. Here is the code I have come up so far, it works ok great only on home page, deeper i go the more links it displays.

```
    function print_languages()
    {
        global $sipnati, $phrase;

        $sql = $sipnati->db->query("
                    SELECT " . (MYSQL_QUERYCACHE ? "SQL_CACHE " : "") . "languageid, languagecode, title, canselect
                    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "language
            ", 0, null, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        $html = '';
        while ($res = $sipnati->db->fetch_array($sql, DB_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $params = $_GET;
                        $params['lang'] = $res['languagecode'];
                        $qs = '?';
                        foreach($params as $k=>$v)
                        {
                          $qs .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
                          $html .= '<a class="flagi" href="' . substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$qs, 0, -1) . '"><img src="images/default/flag-' . $v . '.png" /></a>';
                        }

                    }
                    unset($res);

        return $html;
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You can Implement using PHP Session, which stores the current language information of the user you're currently dealing with.

Comment: Sorry, your question is pretty vague... What does "deeper i go the more links it displays" mean? Please give all relevant information when asking a question, it is not nice to haave people _guess_ what might happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before developing a multilanguage website, take attention to these elements:

- For referencing your website, ONE page link must have ONE and ONLY ONE language.
  e.g http://mydomain.com/mypage.php => Content in English OR another language but not both, even by autodetecting user language. Use http://fr.mydomain.com/mypage.php,  http://mydomain.it/mypage.php or http://mydomain.com/en_US/mypage.php.
  If you don't consider this help, you will kill your own SEO, making it blooding on the floor.
- You can autodetect the user language with $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].
  e.g HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE => fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
- Seperate data by language (one version by language and only one version for each language on your website, avoid french contents on an english website).
  You can use multiple tables (not recommended), multiple database (convenient but unsustainable), multiple rows (convenient but unsustainable) or one row with language reference (conceptually the best solution but it implies a lot of queries.)

For your question... (Yes i have an answer for you :D)
Do you save the selected language in a Session or a Cookie ?
I think we are missing a lot of informations:

- Where you are saving the selected language.
- "deeper i go the more links it displays." What are you meaning ?
- What are you doing with `$params = $_GET; $params['lang'] = $res['languagecode'];` ...
- What is the rest of your language system ?